# How to test private methods with TDD approach in iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, tdd

While implementing TDD for iOS app, I come across a situation where I want to perform TDD for private methods (by writing TDD func first and then adding private methods accordingly, but TDD with private methods looks impossible, because as they are private they can not access by outside class, and TDD test cases will throw compile error as soon as I add private functions).

How to test private methods with TDD approach in iOS app?

Comment: You could change `private` to `internal`.

Comment: there is some purpose why i kept it private, i don't want to explore them outside class. by making it internal, it will break business logic.

Comment: If it is private for reason then you should not change it to internal. It has to be called from a public function, that's how I would test it.

Comment: i am thinking of an approach, where i will make private to internal for during testing, and then write tests, after passing all tests, i will again make them private and disable those tests.

Comment: Since this is for TDD, wouldn’t it make more sense to first write a public method with tests and then refactor part of it into a private method and then use the same tests? How do you know a method should be private directly?

Answer (score 0):

You should not test private functions.
Instead, start with tests for the public functions. And refactor the public function to separate logic to private functions if necessary as you add more tests.
Changing the visibility of a function for testing is a typical anti-pattern that can impact your design.